# Spark sql throws error while reading CDF enabled DELTA table in Azure databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to run the below query in python notebook inside azure databricks

```
tab ='db.t1'

df =spark.sql(f"SELECT MAX(_commit_version) as max_version FROM table_changes({tab},0)")

df.first()["max_version"]
```

But it throws error as below

```
AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITHOUT_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `t1` cannot be resolved. ; line 1 pos 62;
'Project ['MAX('_commit_version) AS max_version#5374]
+- 'UnresolvedTableValuedFunction [table_changes], ['db.t1, 0]
```

Can some some one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table name parameter should be in the quotes (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-change-data-feed#sql)). Try:

```
df =spark.sql(f"SELECT MAX(_commit_version) as max_version FROM table_changes('{tab}',0)")
```

Comment: Exactly , it worked